# Closure return type syntax

Tags: swift, closures

I have the following closure within a struct thats causing some confusion.

```
var response: (result: Result<UserInfo>) -> Void

struct RegisterRequest: Requestable 
{
    let userInfo : [String:AnyObject]
    var response: (result: Result<UserInfo>) -> Void
}
```

Now when I try to implement it, I have the following:

```
let register = RegisterRequest(userInfo: userInfo, response: { (result) in
})
```

If closure syntax is

```
{ (params) -> returnType in 
   statements
}
```

Why is swift auto correcting my implementation to `(result) in` instead of `(Void) in`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block variable `response` is expected to take a single parameter whose type is `Result`, not `Void` or `()`. Thus, Xcode automatically fills in with an argument named `result` representing a `Result` object. Since return type is `Void`, anything after `->` can simply be omitted.

More explicitly, it would be written as:

```
..., response: { (result: Result<UserInfo>) -> Void in
})
```

For the sake of simplicity, it is converted to:

```
..., response: { (result) in
})
```

Parenthesis around arguments can also be omitted:

```
..., response: { result in
})
```

or better with [trailing closure syntax](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax):

```
RegisterRequest(userInfo: userInfo) { result in
  ...
}
```

If you don't want the block taking any parameter, you can define type of that as one of the below:

```
var response: (Void) -> Void
var response: () -> Void
```

Comment: Lets say we have the same block as above but a version that returns a  type called `Model`.  How would the block be rewritten?  `response: { (result) -> Model in }`

Comment: Yes, it would be written exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding that the closure parameters are not the return type.

```
struct RegisterRequest: Requestable 
{
    let userInfo : [String:AnyObject]
    var response: (result: Result<UserInfo>) -> Void
}

let register = RegisterRequest(userInfo: userInfo, response: { (result) in

})
```

Let's add some more parameters that might make it more clear.

```
struct RegisterRequest: Requestable 
{
    let userInfo : [String:AnyObject]
    var response: (result: Result<UserInfo>, myparam1: Int) -> Void
}

let register = RegisterRequest(userInfo: userInfo, response: { (result, p1) in

})
```

And again:

```
struct RegisterRequest: Requestable 
{
    let userInfo : [String:AnyObject]
    var response: (result: Result<UserInfo>, myparam1: Int, myparam2: String) -> Void
}

let register = RegisterRequest(userInfo: userInfo, response: { (result, p1, p2) in

})
```

You will notice that the types do not have to be specified because it is already known.

The parameter names, do not have to match the original declaration. In my example, myparam1 appears in the closure as p1.

Comment: I was under the impression that whatever comes before the "in" is considered the returntype based on this snippet from the apple closure documentation: `{ (params) -> returnType in 
   statements
}`

Comment: What comes after the `->` is the return type of the closure. What comes before `->` are the parameters to the closure. To answer your original question, Xcode puts `(result) in` because it that is what the parameter was named in the declaration.

Comment: Brosef-I too have read that section of the docs and have interpreted it … poorly/wrong. I’m reading this and agreeing that I do not yet understand how to read/interpret the swift docs. 

Wish there were a course I could take. Reading Swift Docs 101.